# Dark Charm and Objective tokens

Tags: descent

I'm playing Descent 2nd edition, in the Shadow Vault scenario.

One of my heroes is carrying the objective token. The Overlord plays Dark Charm targeting that hero.

Can the Overlord force my hero to hand the token over to Baron Zachareth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question to the official developers.

> No, the overlord cannot use Dark Charm to make your hero give the
>   token to Baron Zachareth in The Shadow Vault.
>
> Thanks for playing, Kara Centell-Dunk Game Developer Fantasy Flight
>   Games

Answer (score 3):

In short, **NO**.

My reasoning is based on the two pieces of information:

The Dark Charm card mentioned above has the following text (emphasis mine):

> Play this card on a hero at the start of your turn. The hero tests Willpower. If he passes, draw 1 Overlord card. If he fails, you may perform a **move** or **attack** action with that hero as if he were one of your monsters this turn. You cannot force him to suffer Fatigue or use a Potion, but you may force him to attack himself.

The only two actions that the overlord can take after using this ability is to move or attack.

If that isn't sufficient, trading is described as follows (emphasis mine):

> Heroes may give or receive Shop Item cards, Relic cards, and Search
>   cards to or from **each other** during a move action. At any point during
>   his move action, a hero may trade any number of Shop Item cards, Relic
>   cards, or Search cards with an adjacent hero. Trading does not require an
>   additional action or the expense of movement points.

There's nothing here stating that the hero can trade with an enemy

Comment: But can you force the hero to give items (such as the objective token) to another hero?